# Schengen Visa and Mexico

Tags: air-travel, mexico

I am an Indian citizen and have a Schengen Visa and will be traveling from Delhi to Paris to Mexico. I do not require a visa for Mexico. Do I need to spend a day or so in Paris or can I transit to Mexico City directly? I would like to stay in Paris for a few days on my return trip.

Comment: No, you do not have to go to Paris to use your Schengen visa for entering Mexico

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that you are transiting through CDG (no flights to/from Delhi or Mexico in Orly to my knowledge), then as an Indian citizen, you can do airside transit without a visa.

As you say you have a Schengen visa (but knot knowing anything further about this visa), I would expect that you would be granted entry to France if you wanted to leave the airport.

However, are you sure you do not require a visa for Mexico? Ordinarily Indian nationals do.

Comment: National visa may be substituted with a valid visa or permanent residence documents issued by the US, Canada, Japan, UK or Schengen Area member state to enter Mexico for tourism, transit, or business purposes.

Comment: The Mexican govt site states that if I hold a Schengen Visa I do not require a visa to enter Mexico.i have a Schengen Visa but I do not want to spend time in a Schengen country as I need to attend a wedding in Mexico. However I will be spending some time in Paris on my return to new delhi